# Trigger on Oracle Database inserting data to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle, laravel-5

Please i have a serious issue since a week now and don't know how to do.
I have an oracle 10g database on a production server and a Mysql database on another server. I have to create a trigger which will do that after an insert in a particular table of the oracle database, the new line inserted is copy and insert into the mysql database which hae the same structure.

I wrote the following oracle trigger but i dont know how to connect to the Mysql database from the oracle trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER get_trans AFTER INSERT ON "TABLE" 
    FOR EACH ROW
CALL sendTrans(:new.cust_id, :new.acid, :new.foracid, :new.pstd_date, :new.value_date, :new.tran_id, :new.part_tran_type, :new.tran_amt, :new.clr_bal_amt, :new.tran_particular, :new.sol_id);

CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE sendTrans(cust_id IN INT, acid IN VARCHAR2, foracid IN VARCHAR2, pstd_date IN Datetime, value_date IN Datetime, tran_id IN INT, part_tran_type IN CHAR, tran_amt IN NUMERIC, clr_bal_amt IN NUMERIC, tran_particular IN VARCHAR2, sol_id IN INT)
AS
    INSERT INTO TEMPORALTRANSACTIONTABLE (CUST_ID, ACID, FORACID, PSTD_DATE, DATETIME, VALUE_DATE, TRAN_ID, PART_TRAN_TYPE, TRAN_AMT, CLR_BAL_AMT, TRAN_PARTICULIER, SOL_ID) VALUES (cust_id , acid, foracid, pstd_date, value_date, tran_id, part_tran_type, tran_amt, clr_bal_amt, tran_particular, sol_id)
BEGIN

END sendTrans;
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Questions like "how to do this" without showing any attempt or effort are usually not welcome here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advises. It's normal. As i said, i am on that issuer for a week now. I have been doing effort to solve it sincee but nothing, that's why i came to look for help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup (platform, DB versions) the implementation may differ but on a conceptual level what you need to do is:

1) Create a database link from Oracle to MySQL.

2) Access the table in the MySQL database over the database link.

Your insert statement in the trigger will then look like:

```
INSERT INTO TEMPORALTRANSACTIONTABLE@<YOUR_DATABASE_LINK> (...)
```

Creating a connection and a working database link may proof to be a tricky task.